# OnCLickListener for unknown number of buttons

Tags: java, android

I need a way to make an OnClickListener for unknown number of button from which I then need a way to extract their text. I can't assign every single one of them because as I said I don't know their number and id which I'm almost 80% sure isn't assigned at all. The button are made in a recycleview with text I take form table names of a mysql database.
Code:

```
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.HistoryView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        historyList = new ArrayList<>();
        loadHistory();
```

```
private void loadHistory() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_TABLES,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject history = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                historyList.add(new History(history.getString("0")));
                            }

                            HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(MainActivity.this, historyList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                            String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + jsonError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: You can try to use arraylists ? for storing of Jbuttons and loop them through and add the listener

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a reference to the RecyclerView.

```
for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    recyclerView.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        Button button = (Button) v
        System.out.println(button.getText())
    });
}
```

Note: The method TextView.getText() returns a CharSequence, not a String.

Note: If the RecyclerView has other views in it, check v instanceOf Button before casting!

Comment: Quick question where should I run the loop , obviosly after I assign the buttons but in OnCreate right?

Comment: Yes, but don't do the loop if you have a reference to the buttons at some point in onCreate(), in this case just add them to an ArrayList or directly add the onClickListener. But if you are using a function which automatically creates the buttons for you, you can do this.

Comment: is there supposed to not have any semicolon at all in the setOnClickListener and System.out.println doesn't work on android java so do you know how to make it with Toast